# remove /public in laravel on Apache server and webuzo panel

Tags: laravel, apache, centos7

I want to remove /public in the URL i want to use virtual host not changing server.php into index.php.

i'm useing webuzo admin panel i add this lines to apache config file 
but it seems its not working 
please help me what should i do

my server is centOs 7 and my project is on laravel 5.8

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName uptodate.pnashr.pub

ServerAdmin webmaster@mawpro.me
DocumentRoot /home/uptodateadmin/public_html/public

<Directory /home/uptodateadmin/public_html/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have testing your VirtualHost config, nothing wrong with that code.

You have to make sure your public .htaccess is default from laravel and not deleted. Webuzo will already regenerate VirtualHost config everytimes we add new domain or subdomain web. So set document root from webuzo admin panel not change manually from apache config file.

> Actually VirtualHost not change server.php to index.php but server.php
>   located at parent directory and document root at subfolder public.

You can make server.php file and include "../server.php"; inside that file

Don't forget to check you .htaccess. Just use default .htaccess from laravel

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: how can i set document root in webuzo panel?

Comment: when you add web hosting, that have option document root. if your apache run manually from linux then you can config manual. Use your VirtualHost config should work well. Make sure it's not a domain problem too.

Comment: my domain document root is set to public_html should i change it to public_html/public ?

Answer (score 0):

so you want to make laravel for share hosting its easy

make a folder with any name in my case its root

move all data to root except public folder

now rename your public folder with public_html

your file structure should look like this

[image]

now open public_html/index.php define your bootstrap and autoload
page should look like this or you can copy all code from here

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));



require __DIR__.'/../root/vendor/autoload.php';



$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../root/bootstrap/app.php';

// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

that's it now your public_html is public for users
root file should be in back because this files should not expose to public

Answer (score 0):

In Webuzo you can change the document root at:

```
/usr/local/apps/apache/etc/conf.d/webuzoVH.conf
```